# Is there a way to be notified on ObjectBox Dart model changes?

Tags: flutter, dart, database-migration, objectbox

I am currently working with ObjectBox Dart and I would like to perform migration during data model changes, for example, populating data into the new column. However, I don't find any way to do it. Is there a way to do what I want?

I tried checking the parameters of `openStore` function and methods of `Store` class. But none of it is relevant to my problem.

Answer (score 0):

As ObjectBox works with annotated Dart objects rather than an explicit schema to define the database model there is no such thing as a migration. A typical way of handling new properties is to add fallback logic or similar to the getters and setters of a class or your business logic (e.g. return a default value if the database value is null).